# Make two adjacent divs equal height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a calendar that I am trying to create for a client. I want the sidebar to be the same height as the calendar without setting an explicit px size as this needs to be responsive. I have searched around 20 other questions similar to mine on here and I haven't found a solution to it yet. The html and css for this calendar are below.

```css
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
}

*,
*::before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible
}

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1rem
}

a {
  background-color: transparent
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder
}

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1rem
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25rem
}

sup {
  top: -.25rem
}

img {
  border-style: none
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.15;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

fieldset {
  padding: .35rem .75rem .625rem
}

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto
}

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px
}

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit
}

details {
  display: block
}

summary {
  display: list-item
}

template {
  display: none
}

[hidden] {
  display: none
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}

blockquote::before,
blockquote::after,
q::before,
q::after {
  content: '';
  content: none
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Advent Pro ExtraLight"), local("AdventPro-ExtraLight"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjfWMPbJ4C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Advent Pro ExtraLight"), local("AdventPro-ExtraLight"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjfWMPb94C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Advent Pro ExtraLight"), local("AdventPro-ExtraLight"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjfWMPbF4Cw.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Advent Pro Regular"), local("AdventPro-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTmtKI5Z.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Advent Pro Regular"), local("AdventPro-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTStKI5Z.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Advent Pro Regular"), local("AdventPro-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTqtKA.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local("Advent Pro SemiBold"), local("AdventPro-SemiBold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjeWJPbJ4C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local("Advent Pro SemiBold"), local("AdventPro-SemiBold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjeWJPb94C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local("Advent Pro SemiBold"), local("AdventPro-SemiBold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjeWJPbF4Cw.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Advent Pro Bold"), local("AdventPro-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjYGIPbJ4C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Advent Pro Bold"), local("AdventPro-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjYGIPb94C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Advent Pro Bold"), local("AdventPro-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjYGIPbF4Cw.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font: normal 700 2rem/3rem 'Advent Pro';
  color: #212121;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 600
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2.875rem
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120em) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 4.25rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240em) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 7.875rem
  }
}

a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212121;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: inherit;
  transition: color 100ms cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) 0s
}

a:hover {
  color: #FFB819;
  transition: color 100ms cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) 0s
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120em) {
  p {
    margin: 1rem 0
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240em) {
  p {
    margin: 2.5rem 0
  }
}

::selection,
*::selection {
  background: #FFB819;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none
}

.calendar-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0;
  background-color: #FFB819;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2rem;
  align-content: stretch
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-sidebar {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: .5rem 0 0 .5rem;
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem
  }
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left,
.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5rem
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .dayofweek,
.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .monthofdate {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  display: block
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .dayofweek,
  .calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .monthofdate {
    font-size: 4rem
  }
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: .5rem
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right .numdate {
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-weight: 700
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right .numdate {
    font-size: 11rem
  }
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentevents {
  padding: 4rem 2rem 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentevents ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 2.5rem
}

.calendar-base {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-base {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0 2rem 0 0
  }
}

.calendar-base .yearNav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem
}

.calendar-base .yearNav a,
.calendar-base .yearNav h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}

.calendar-base .monthNav {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)
}

.calendar-base .monthNav .month {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #aaa
}

.calendar-base .monthNav .month.active {
  color: #FFB819
}

.calendar-base .hrbreak {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem
}

.calendar-base .hrbreak .break {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242
}

.calendar-base .weekdays {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr)
}

.calendar-base .weekdays .weekday {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #aaa;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 0 2rem 0
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid>* {
  border: 1px solid white
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid>*:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day.today {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFB819;
  color: white;
  margin: 20%
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day.last-month,
.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day.next-month {
  color: #aaa
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day .event-indicator {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2980B9;
  top: 304px;
  left: 695px
}

.calendar-base .months {
  color: #aaa;
  word-spacing: 10px
}

.posts {
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

.posts:hover {
  color: #27e879 !important
}

.create-event {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px
}

.event-line {
  width: 90%
}

.add-event {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid white 2px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 42px;
  left: 260px
}

.add {
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 10px
}

.add:hover,
.create-event:hover,
.add-event:hover {
  color: #27e879 !important;
  border-color: #27e879 !important
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTqtKA.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTStKI5Z.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container cal">
    <div class="calendar-sidebar">
      <div class="currentdate">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="dayofweek">wednesday
            <?php ?>
          </div>
          <div class="monthofdate">february
            <?php ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="numdate">27
            <?php  ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="currentevents">Current Events
        <ul>
          <li>Toddler Time
            <ul>
              <li>10:00AM</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-base">
      <div class="yearNav">
        <a class="yearlink" onclick="openYear(event, 'Next')">&nbsp;&gt;</a>
        <h4>&nbsp;
          2019&nbsp;</h4>
        <a class="tablinks" onclick="openYear(event, 'Previous')">&lt;&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="monthNav">
        <a class="month">Jan</a>
        <a class="month active">Feb</a>
        <a class="month">Mar</a>
        <a class="month">Apr</a>
        <a class="month">May</a>
        <a class="month">Jun</a>
        <a class="month">Jul</a>
        <a class="month">Aug</a>
        <a class="month">Sep</a>
        <a class="month">Oct</a>
        <a class="month">Nov</a>
        <a class="month">Dec</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hrbreak">
        <div class="break"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="weekdays">
        <div class="weekday">sun</div>
        <div class="weekday">mon</div>
        <div class="weekday">tue</div>
        <div class="weekday">wed</div>
        <div class="weekday">thu</div>
        <div class="weekday">fri</div>
        <div class="weekday">sat</div>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-grid">
        <div id="jan27" class="day last-month">27</div>
        <div id="jan28" class="day last-month">28</div>
        <div id="jan29" class="day last-month">29</div>
        <div id="jan30" class="day last-month">30</div>
        <div id="jan31" class="day last-month">31</div>
        <div id="feb01" class="day">1</div>
        <div id="feb02" class="day">2</div>
        <div id="feb03" class="day">3</div>
        <div id="feb04" class="day">4</div>
        <div id="feb05" class="day">5</div>
        <div id="feb06" class="day">6</div>
        <div id="feb07" class="day">7</div>
        <div id="feb08" class="day">8</div>
        <div id="feb09" class="day">9</div>
        <div id="feb10" class="day">10</div>
        <div id="feb11" class="day">11</div>
        <div id="feb12" class="day">12</div>
        <div id="feb13" class="day">13</div>
        <div id="feb14" class="day">14</div>
        <div id="feb15" class="day">15</div>
        <div id="feb16" class="day">16</div>
        <div id="feb17" class="day">17</div>
        <div id="feb18" class="day">18</div>
        <div id="feb19" class="day">19</div>
        <div id="feb20" class="day">20</div>
        <div id="feb21" class="day">21</div>
        <div id="feb22" class="day">22</div>
        <div id="feb23" class="day">23</div>
        <div id="feb24" class="day">24</div>
        <div id="feb25" class="day">25
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="feb26" class="day">26
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="feb27" class="day today">27
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="feb28" class="day">28</div>
        <div id="mar01" class="day next-month">1</div>
        <div id="mar02" class="day next-month">2
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="mar03" class="day next-month">3</div>
        <div id="mar04" class="day next-month">4</div>
        <div id="mar05" class="day next-month">5</div>
        <div id="mar06" class="day next-month">6</div>
        <div id="mar07" class="day next-month">7</div>
        <div id="mar08" class="day next-month">8</div>
        <div id="mar09" class="day next-month">9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to find a CSS solution for this and not use JavaScript if I don't have to.

The second problem I am having is getting the event-indicator to display at the top of the `div` that it is inside of rather than showing up at the bottom of the calendar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**

You only have to add the property `align-items: stretch;` into the `.container` element.

Here is the .container class

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  z-index: 1
}
```

I tested it here:  [JSFiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/e37jz49d/)

For more about flexbox, go to [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Second question:**

You should to remove the `top` and `left` properties`.event-indicator`, because they move it too far from the position that you want, and to make it appear under the number, just put `z-index: -1`.

The class should be like bellow:

```
.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day .event-indicator {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 5px; */
    /* height: 5px; */
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #2980B9;
    /* top: 304px; */
    /* left: 695px; */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Note: I'm not sure about the style that you want, but i edited the `width` and `height` of the `.event-indicator`, because they were to small to be seen, but you may add the size that you want.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yfpbtwa/1/)

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update your container, not to align the items to the center, by doing that the flex container is no longer matching the height of the children to try center them. Hope this helps. Regards!

```css
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
}

*,
*::before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible
}

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1rem
}

a {
  background-color: transparent
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder
}

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1rem
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25rem
}

sup {
  top: -.25rem
}

img {
  border-style: none
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.15;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

fieldset {
  padding: .35rem .75rem .625rem
}

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto
}

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px
}

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit
}

details {
  display: block
}

summary {
  display: list-item
}

template {
  display: none
}

[hidden] {
  display: none
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}

blockquote::before,
blockquote::after,
q::before,
q::after {
  content: '';
  content: none
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Advent Pro ExtraLight"), local("AdventPro-ExtraLight"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjfWMPbJ4C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Advent Pro ExtraLight"), local("AdventPro-ExtraLight"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjfWMPb94C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Advent Pro ExtraLight"), local("AdventPro-ExtraLight"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjfWMPbF4Cw.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Advent Pro Regular"), local("AdventPro-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTmtKI5Z.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Advent Pro Regular"), local("AdventPro-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTStKI5Z.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Advent Pro Regular"), local("AdventPro-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTqtKA.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local("Advent Pro SemiBold"), local("AdventPro-SemiBold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjeWJPbJ4C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local("Advent Pro SemiBold"), local("AdventPro-SemiBold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjeWJPb94C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local("Advent Pro SemiBold"), local("AdventPro-SemiBold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjeWJPbF4Cw.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Advent Pro Bold"), local("AdventPro-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjYGIPbJ4C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Advent Pro Bold"), local("AdventPro-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjYGIPb94C-s0.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Advent Pro Bold"), local("AdventPro-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mDoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwjYGIPbF4Cw.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font: normal 700 2rem/3rem 'Advent Pro';
  color: #212121;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 600
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2.875rem
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120em) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 4.25rem
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240em) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 7.875rem
  }
}

a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212121;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: inherit;
  transition: color 100ms cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) 0s
}

a:hover {
  color: #FFB819;
  transition: color 100ms cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) 0s
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120em) {
  p {
    margin: 1rem 0
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240em) {
  p {
    margin: 2.5rem 0
  }
}

::selection,
*::selection {
  background: #FFB819;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none
}

.calendar-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0;
  background-color: #FFB819;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2rem;
  align-content: stretch
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-sidebar {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: .5rem 0 0 .5rem;
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem
  }
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left,
.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5rem
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .dayofweek,
.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .monthofdate {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  display: block
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .dayofweek,
  .calendar-sidebar .currentdate .left .monthofdate {
    font-size: 4rem
  }
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: .5rem
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right .numdate {
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-weight: 700
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-sidebar .currentdate .right .numdate {
    font-size: 11rem
  }
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentevents {
  padding: 4rem 2rem 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.calendar-sidebar .currentevents ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 2.5rem
}

.calendar-base {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .calendar-base {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0 2rem 0 0
  }
}

.calendar-base .yearNav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem
}

.calendar-base .yearNav a,
.calendar-base .yearNav h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}

.calendar-base .monthNav {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)
}

.calendar-base .monthNav .month {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #aaa
}

.calendar-base .monthNav .month.active {
  color: #FFB819
}

.calendar-base .hrbreak {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem
}

.calendar-base .hrbreak .break {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242
}

.calendar-base .weekdays {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr)
}

.calendar-base .weekdays .weekday {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #aaa;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 0 2rem 0
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid>* {
  border: 1px solid white
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid>*:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day.today {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFB819;
  color: white;
  margin: 20%
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day.last-month,
.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day.next-month {
  color: #aaa
}

.calendar-base .calendar-grid .day .event-indicator {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2980B9;
  top: 304px;
  left: 695px
}

.calendar-base .months {
  color: #aaa;
  word-spacing: 10px
}

.posts {
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

.posts:hover {
  color: #27e879 !important
}

.create-event {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px
}

.event-line {
  width: 90%
}

.add-event {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid white 2px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 42px;
  left: 260px
}

.add {
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 10px
}

.add:hover,
.create-event:hover,
.add-event:hover {
  color: #27e879 !important;
  border-color: #27e879 !important
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTqtKA.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v7/V8mAoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwhTStKI5Z.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container cal">
    <div class="calendar-sidebar">
      <div class="currentdate">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="dayofweek">wednesday
            <?php ?>
          </div>
          <div class="monthofdate">february
            <?php ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="numdate">27
            <?php  ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="currentevents">Current Events
        <ul>
          <li>Toddler Time
            <ul>
              <li>10:00AM</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-base">
      <div class="yearNav">
        <a class="yearlink" onclick="openYear(event, 'Next')">&nbsp;&gt;</a>
        <h4>&nbsp;
          2019&nbsp;</h4>
        <a class="tablinks" onclick="openYear(event, 'Previous')">&lt;&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="monthNav">
        <a class="month">Jan</a>
        <a class="month active">Feb</a>
        <a class="month">Mar</a>
        <a class="month">Apr</a>
        <a class="month">May</a>
        <a class="month">Jun</a>
        <a class="month">Jul</a>
        <a class="month">Aug</a>
        <a class="month">Sep</a>
        <a class="month">Oct</a>
        <a class="month">Nov</a>
        <a class="month">Dec</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hrbreak">
        <div class="break"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="weekdays">
        <div class="weekday">sun</div>
        <div class="weekday">mon</div>
        <div class="weekday">tue</div>
        <div class="weekday">wed</div>
        <div class="weekday">thu</div>
        <div class="weekday">fri</div>
        <div class="weekday">sat</div>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-grid">
        <div id="jan27" class="day last-month">27</div>
        <div id="jan28" class="day last-month">28</div>
        <div id="jan29" class="day last-month">29</div>
        <div id="jan30" class="day last-month">30</div>
        <div id="jan31" class="day last-month">31</div>
        <div id="feb01" class="day">1</div>
        <div id="feb02" class="day">2</div>
        <div id="feb03" class="day">3</div>
        <div id="feb04" class="day">4</div>
        <div id="feb05" class="day">5</div>
        <div id="feb06" class="day">6</div>
        <div id="feb07" class="day">7</div>
        <div id="feb08" class="day">8</div>
        <div id="feb09" class="day">9</div>
        <div id="feb10" class="day">10</div>
        <div id="feb11" class="day">11</div>
        <div id="feb12" class="day">12</div>
        <div id="feb13" class="day">13</div>
        <div id="feb14" class="day">14</div>
        <div id="feb15" class="day">15</div>
        <div id="feb16" class="day">16</div>
        <div id="feb17" class="day">17</div>
        <div id="feb18" class="day">18</div>
        <div id="feb19" class="day">19</div>
        <div id="feb20" class="day">20</div>
        <div id="feb21" class="day">21</div>
        <div id="feb22" class="day">22</div>
        <div id="feb23" class="day">23</div>
        <div id="feb24" class="day">24</div>
        <div id="feb25" class="day">25
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="feb26" class="day">26
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="feb27" class="day today">27
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="feb28" class="day">28</div>
        <div id="mar01" class="day next-month">1</div>
        <div id="mar02" class="day next-month">2
          <div class="event-indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="mar03" class="day next-month">3</div>
        <div id="mar04" class="day next-month">4</div>
        <div id="mar05" class="day next-month">5</div>
        <div id="mar06" class="day next-month">6</div>
        <div id="mar07" class="day next-month">7</div>
        <div id="mar08" class="day next-month">8</div>
        <div id="mar09" class="day next-month">9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```